# Unattended installation of Azure SDK via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure, windows-installer, unattended-processing

I'm having problems to create an unattended installation of cmdlets of Azure (It's a msi file, windowsazure-powershell.0.8.3.msi, current version).

How can I know the parameters that installation needs and how I should write it?

In this way?

```
$msifile= '<path>\windowsazure-powershell.0.8.3.msi' 
$arguments= ' /qn /l*v .\options.txt' 
Start-Process `
 -file  $msifile `
 -arg $arguments `
 -passthru | wait-process
```

So how can I perform that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about all the commandline switches. You can do this using WMI and PowerShell

```
$product= [WMICLASS]"\\.\ROOT\CIMV2:win32_Product"
$product.Install("c:\temp\windowsazure-powershell.0.8.3.msi")
```

Comment: Ravikanth, thank you very much for your answer but I have a question related with your reply.

What vmi class should I use to install this without take care about parameters? I looked up for this but I didn't get something useful for this case.

Thank you again.

Comment: The WMI class that helps with MSI installs is Win32_Product. You can simply run the code I provided. A return code 0 means that the MSI install was successful. No other parameters needed.